# If $I\propto x,y,z$ how can I express a function $I=f(x,y,z)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

As the title;

If $I\propto x,y,z$.

How can I express a function $I=f(x,y,z)$?

**CA** : $I=f(x,y,z)=kxyz$ ,  for some  $k$.

I'm not sure how this answer is derived?

Comment: by definition ${}$

Comment: I'm not sure what definition you mean , am I missing something obvious? I

Comment: The definition is that which you have already typed.